# CECIL IsGenericInstance not returns correct value for out put parameter

Tags: mono, mono.cecil

I have below method with nullable parameters in which 2nd one is out too

```
public static void MyMethod(Nullable<System.Int32> i_ReportID, out Nullable<System.Int32> i_MenuID)
        {
            i_MenuID = 0;
        }
```

I tried to identify the parameter as a GenericInstance by

(methodDefinition.Parameters[0] as ParameterReference).ParameterType.IsGenericInstance
**For 1st parameter and it's returns true.**
(methodDefinition.Parameters[1] as ParameterReference).ParameterType.IsGenericInstance
**For 2nd parameter and it's returns false. Why?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be used with ByReferenceType like below

(parameter.ParameterType as ByReferenceType).ElementType.IsGenericInstance

Afterwards I am getting correct IsGenericInstance value